# How can I make a value becomes "NULL" where the API response have "missing subset"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I'm storing data from an API and for some response of different country, some of the subsets is not provided, thus when I tried to subset and use the `.get()` method it return KeyError.

I'm wondering how I can ignore these variable and return null value when the data is not provided by the API response.

Below is the json response of two different country:
**businessreport_ES.json**

```
    "salesAndTrafficByAsin": [{
        "parentAsin": "AX0003",
        "childAsin": "AXC0001",
        "sku": "AXC1",
        "salesByAsin": {
            "unitsOrdered": 1,
            "orderedProductSales": {
                "amount": 31.06,
                "currencyCode": "EUR"
            },
            "totalOrderItems": 1
        },
        "trafficByAsin": {
            "browserSessions": 0,
            "mobileAppSessions": 1,
            "sessions": 1,
            "browserSessionPercentage": 0.0,
            "mobileAppSessionPercentage": 50.0,
            "sessionPercentage": 14.29,
            "browserPageViews": 0,
            "mobileAppPageViews": 9,
            "pageViews": 9,
            "browserPageViewsPercentage": 0.0,
            "mobileAppPageViewsPercentage": 90.0,
            "pageViewsPercentage": 56.25,
            "buyBoxPercentage": 100.0,
            "unitSessionPercentage": 100.0
        }]
```

**businessreport_UK.json**

```
    "salesAndTrafficByAsin": [{
        "parentAsin": "AX0003",
        "childAsin": "AXC0001",
        "sku": "AXC1",
        "salesByAsin": {
            "unitsOrdered": 0,
            "unitsOrderedB2B": 0,
            "orderedProductSales": {
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currencyCode": "GBP"
            },
            "orderedProductSalesB2B": {
                "amount": 0.0,
                "currencyCode": "GBP"
            },
            "totalOrderItems": 0,
            "totalOrderItemsB2B": 0
        },
        "trafficByAsin": {
            "browserSessions": 3,
            "browserSessionsB2B": 0,
            "mobileAppSessions": 12,
            "mobileAppSessionsB2B": 0,
            "sessions": 15,
            "sessionsB2B": 0,
            "browserSessionPercentage": 0.16,
            "browserSessionPercentageB2B": 0.0,
            "mobileAppSessionPercentage": 0.47,
            "mobileAppSessionPercentageB2B": 0.0,
            "sessionPercentage": 0.34,
            "sessionPercentageB2B": 0.0,
            "browserPageViews": 3,
            "browserPageViewsB2B": 0,
            "mobileAppPageViews": 15,
            "mobileAppPageViewsB2B": 0,
            "pageViews": 18,
            "pageViewsB2B": 0,
            "browserPageViewsPercentage": 0.12,
            "browserPageViewsPercentageB2B": 0.0,
            "mobileAppPageViewsPercentage": 0.46,
            "mobileAppPageViewsPercentageB2B": 0.0,
            "pageViewsPercentage": 0.31,
            "pageViewsPercentageB2B": 0.0,
            "buyBoxPercentage": 0.0,
            "buyBoxPercentageB2B": 0.0,
            "unitSessionPercentage": 0.0,
            "unitSessionPercentageB2B": 0.0
        }
    }]
```

Below is my code:

```
        f = open(f'./responses/businessreport_{marketplace}.json')
        jsondata = json.load(f)
        salesAndTrafficByAsin = []

        for item in jsondata['salesAndTrafficByAsin']:
            salesAndTrafficByAsin.append({
                "date": pd.to_datetime(datef),
                "parentAsin": item.get('parentAsin'),
                "childAsin": item.get('childAsin'),
                'unitsOrdered': item["salesByAsin"].get('unitsOrdered'),
                'unitsOrderedB2B': item["salesByAsin"].get('unitsOrderedB2B'),
                'orderedProductSales': item["salesByAsin"]['orderedProductSales'].get('amount'),
                'currencyCode': item["salesByAsin"]['orderedProductSales'].get('currencyCode'),
                'orderedProductSales_B2B': item["salesByAsin"]['orderedProductSalesB2B'].get('amount'),
                'currencyCode_B2B': item["salesByAsin"]['orderedProductSalesB2B'].get('currencyCode'),
                'browserSessions': item["trafficByAsin"].get('browserSessions'),
                "browserSessionsB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('browserSessionsB2B'),
                "mobileAppSessions": item["trafficByAsin"].get('mobileAppSessions'),
                "mobileAppSessionsB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('mobileAppSessionsB2B'),
                "sessions": item["trafficByAsin"].get('sessions'),
                "sessionsB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('sessionsB2B'),
                "browserSessionPercentage": item["trafficByAsin"].get('browserSessionPercentage'),
                "browserSessionPercentageB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('browserSessionPercentageB2B'),
                "mobileAppSessionPercentage": item["trafficByAsin"].get('mobileAppSessionPercentage'),
                "mobileAppSessionPercentageB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('mobileAppSessionPercentageB2B'),
                "sessionPercentage": item["trafficByAsin"].get('sessionPercentage'),
                "sessionPercentageB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('sessionPercentageB2B'),
                "browserPageViews": item["trafficByAsin"].get('browserPageViews'),
                "browserPageViewsB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('browserPageViewsB2B'),
                "mobileAppPageViews": item["trafficByAsin"].get('mobileAppPageViews'),
                "mobileAppPageViewsB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('mobileAppPageViewsB2B'),
                "pageViews": item["trafficByAsin"].get('pageViews'),
                "pageViewsB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('pageViewsB2B'),
                "browserPageViewsPercentage": item["trafficByAsin"].get('browserPageViewsPercentage'),
                "browserPageViewsPercentageB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('browserPageViewsPercentageB2B'),
                "mobileAppPageViewsPercentage": item["trafficByAsin"].get('mobileAppPageViewsPercentage'),
                "mobileAppPageViewsPercentageB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('mobileAppPageViewsPercentageB2B'),
                "pageViewsPercentage": item["trafficByAsin"].get('pageViewsPercentage'),
                "pageViewsPercentageB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('pageViewsPercentageB2B'),
                "buyBoxPercentage": item["trafficByAsin"].get('buyBoxPercentage'),
                "buyBoxPercentageB2B": item["trafficByAsin"].get('buyBoxPercentageB2B'),



            })
```

So the difference here is that buesinessreport_UK.json have the orderedProductSalesB2B subset while buesinessreport_ES.json dont. So the code return the error as shown below when trying to loop the buesinessreport_ES.json data

```
     46 salesAndTrafficByDate = []
     47 for item in jsondata['salesAndTrafficByDate']:
     48     salesAndTrafficByDate.append({
     49         "date": pd.to_datetime(item.get('date')),
     50         "orderedProductSales": item["salesByDate"]['orderedProductSales'].get('amount'),
     51         "CurrencyCode": item["salesByDate"]['orderedProductSales'].get('currencyCode'),
---> 52         "orderedProductSales_B2B": item["salesByDate"]['orderedProductSalesB2B'].get('amount'),
     53         "CurrencyCode_B2B": item["salesByDate"]['orderedProductSalesB2B'].get('currencyCode'),
     54         "unitsOrdered": item["salesByDate"].get("unitsOrdered"),
     55         "unitsOrdered_B2B": item["salesByDate"].get("unitsOrderedB2B"),
     56         "totalOrderItems": item["salesByDate"].get("totalOrderItems"),
     57         "totalOrderItems_B2B": item["salesByDate"].get("totalOrderItemsB2B"),
     58         "averageSalesPerOrderItem": item["salesByDate"]["averageSalesPerOrderItem"].get("amount"),
     59         "averageSalesPerOrderItem_B2B": item["salesByDate"]["averageSalesPerOrderItemB2B"].get("amount"),
     60         "averageUnitsPerOrderItem": item["salesByDate"].get("averageUnitsPerOrderItem"),
     61         "averageUnitsPerOrderItem_B2B": item["salesByDate"].get("averageUnitsPerOrderItem"),
     62         "averageSellingPrice": item["salesByDate"]["averageSellingPrice"].get("amount"),
     63         "averageSellingPrice_B2B": item["salesByDate"]["averageSellingPriceB2B"].get("amount"),
     64         "unitsRefunded": item["salesByDate"].get("unitsRefunded"),
     65         "refundRate": item["salesByDate"].get("refundRate"),
     66         "claimsGranted": item["salesByDate"].get("claimsGranted"),
     67         "claimsAmount": item["salesByDate"]["claimsAmount"].get("amount"),
...
     71     })
     72 salesAndTrafficByAsin = []
     74 for item in jsondata['salesAndTrafficByAsin']:

KeyError: 'orderedProductSalesB2B'
```

Comment: A dictionary's *get()* method will **not** raise KeyError

Comment: Yes, but since I am trying to access the first level of Nested Dict using Square Brackets and then use the .get method to access to the second level of the nested dict, hence it return the keyerror. Is there anyway around that i can get access to these multiple level of nested dict without the keyerror?

Comment: Yes. There are several ways around this problem one of which is to use a try/except for KeyError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imho you should use multiple `get`s chained, cause that's what they were designed for i.a.

I wouldn't recommend it to be honest, but you can define a method to "safely" get values from a nested dictionary.

- loop over "nested keys"
- reassign the result
- return the result OR default if the key is not present at some level of nesting

```py
def nested_get(d, *keys, default=None):
  """
  Return value from nested dictionary
  nested_get(d, "a","b") == d["a"]["b"]
  """
  for k in keys:
    try:
      d = d[k]
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
      return default
  return d

a = {"w":{"d":5}}
b = {"x":{"D": 5}}
value = nested_get(b,"x","D")
print(value) # This prints 5
value = nested_get(a,"w","d","t")
print(value) # This prints "None"
value = nested_get(a,"w","d","t", default = 11)
print(value) # This prints 11
```